# ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed soft link in path

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a simple procedure to insert image into my database.

Error suggests that there are some soft links so I checked the files with `file` and here are results :

```
[oracle@term-2-15 home]$ file /home/oracle/laborki/champion_images
/home/oracle/laborki/champion_images: directory
[oracle@term-2-15 home]$ file /home/oracle/laborki/champion_images/ahri.jpg
/home/oracle/laborki/champion_images/ahri.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

Table where i want to put an image :

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    image ORDImage,
    modified_image ORDImage,
    image_name VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_IMAGE (
  image_name IN VARCHAR2,
  directory_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  ord_image ORDImage;
  ctx RAW(64) := NULL;
  row_id UROWID;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO images(image, image_name)
  VALUES (ORDImage.init('FILE', directory_name, image_name), image_name)
  RETURNING image, rowid INTO ord_image, row_id;
  ord_image.import(ctx);
  UPDATE images SET image = ord_image WHERE rowid = row_id;
END;
```

And how I call it

```
DECLARE
  image_name VARCHAR2(8) := 'ahri.jpg';
  directory_name VARCHAR2(50) := 'CHAMPION_IMAGES';
BEGIN
  LOAD_IMAGE(image_name, directory_name);
END;
```

As a system user I also did that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY champion_images AS '/home/oracle/laborki/champion_images';

Grant all on directory champion_images to bazy
```

When i call my procedure i got that message :

```
Error report -
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
soft link in path
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDSOURCE", line 183
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 822
ORA-06512: at "ORDPLUGINS.ORDX_FILE_SOURCE", line 57
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDSOURCE", line 164
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMG_PKG", line 1215
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", line 738
ORA-06512: at "BAZY.LOAD_IMAGE", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 5
22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
*Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
*Action:   See the next error message in the error stack for more detailed
           information.  Also, verify that the file or LOB exists and that
           the necessary privileges are set for the specified operation. If
           the error still persists, report the error to the DBA.
```

I did not manage to find any soft links so I am not sure what is actually wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the entire path: /home, /home/oracle, /home/oracle/laborki, and /home/oracle/laborki/champion_images. Best of luck.

Comment: Oh right, thanks the problem was `home` directory :)

Comment: Thanks both! For other readers: they meant, one should do this at the linux shell (for each folder):  "ls -la /home". For me this returns "lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 May 31  2019 /home -> /u01/userhome". 
This shows  /home is a soft link to /u01/userhome